# mail() and phpmailer() send feature not working from cpanel but works fine on localhost

Tags: php, email, cpanel

As the title suggests, ive tried every type of mail() feature from different websites and when using the phpmailer code it is throwing the HTTP ERROR 500. I dont necessarily want the phpmailer to work, just the simple mail() would be fine. On the following code, i get sent email message but never receive the email.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
$subject="test";
$message="test";
$status = mail('************@live.com', $subject, $message, $header);
//$to mail hidden for security purpose
if($status)
{ 
    echo '<p>Your mail has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, Please try again!</p>'; 
}
?>
```

There might be a problem with php.ini which dont allow sending mails but i cant find that in Cpanel. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some server not sent mail,You need to sent mail from smtp but before it,you need to setup smtp configure in your cpanel.

Comment: i can send mails from webmail feature, but cant do it from code. i would like custom auto generated email codes otherwise the webmail would have been enough for me